# query two events for on

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with links on top.  When a link is clicked it scrolls down to a particular section.  For styling purposes, I had to write a small jQuery to have to land 100px above the actual section that it scrolls to.  Now I need the pixel number to change depending on the media query.  Is there something wrong about how this is written?  The responsive part isn't working..

```
    function offsetAnchor() {

        if(jQuery(location.hash).length !== 0) {
            if (jQuery(window).width() <= 350) {
                window.scrollTo(window.scrollX, window.scrollY - 180);
            }

            else {
                window.scrollTo(window.scrollX, window.scrollY - 100);
            }
        }
    }

    // This will capture hash changes while you are on the same page
    jQuery(window).on("hashchange", function () {
        offsetAnchor();
    });


    window.setTimeout(function() {
        offsetAnchor();
    }, 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

the syntax should be :

```
jQuery(window).on("hashchange resize", function () {}
```

you can read more about `.on()` function at [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Thank you, but but would you happen to know why the function isn't actually doing what its supposed to - changing changing the offset based on screen size?